# How to prove that a sequence diverges using the Cauchy definition?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

It was a question of my integral calculus exam:

*Write the Cauchy definition of*
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  a_n  = L$

So, I literally wrote:

" $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence if given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall\ m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ if $n,m\ge N$, then $|a_n - a_m|<\epsilon$, or with symbols:

$\forall\epsilon>0:\exists N\in\mathbb{N}:\forall\ m,n \in\mathbb{N}: m,n\ge N\implies |a_n - a_m|<\epsilon$.

And if $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  a_n  = L$  ( i.e. $\{a_n\}$ converges) "

The following question was:

*With this definition, find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  (3n+2)$*

And that is what I did:

I proposed that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  (3n+2)   = \infty$ i.e.  $\{3n+2\}$ diverges.  So I think that I have to prove that this limit is equal to infinity using the Cauchy definition.

But if a sequence $\{a_n\}$ diverges $\implies$ $\{a_n\}$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

And $\{a_n\}$ is not a Cauchy sequence if

$\exists\epsilon>0:\forall N\in\mathbb{N}:\exists\ m,n \in\mathbb{N}:$   $m,n\ge N$ and $|a_n - a_m|\ge\epsilon$ $(1)$

So, I must to prove $(1)$.

$(1)$ says that there **exists** $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that ..., so $(1)$ has not to apply $\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, and for this fact (I think) I can assign convinient values to $m,n$ in order to prove $(1)$:

If i choose $m=N+1,n=N$ then $|3(N+1)+2 -(3N+2)|=3>2$.

So exists $\epsilon=2>0 $ such that $\forall N \in\mathbb{N}:$
there exists $m=N+1, n=N$ such that $N+1,N \ge N$ and $|3(N+1)+2 -(3N+2)|=3>\epsilon$.

Hence $\{3n+2\}$ is not a Cauchy sequence $\implies$  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  (3n+2)   = \infty$.

Is my proof correct? If it is not correct, could you help me proving that, please?

Comment: just reading quick, it looks perfectly good to me

Comment: I will note that, at the end, we cannot just say that $$\text{$\{a_n\}$ not Cauchy$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$}$$We can only say that $$\text{$\{a_n\}$ not Cauchy$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\notin\Bbb R$}$$The limit may be $\pm\infty$ or just non-existent.

Comment: But if i i want to prove that the limit is $ \infty$, what have i to do?

Comment: @KarenSM You have to show that for each $M >0$, there is a natural number $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $a_n\geq M$. Quite trivial, you can take $N=[M]$, where $[M]$ is the “floor” of $M$, the unique integer satisfying $M-1< [M] \leq M$.

Comment: @LiChunMin but i need to prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  (3n+2)   = \infty$ using the cauchy definition

Comment: @KarenSM Above is the definition of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n = +\infty$…as far as I know, Cauchy did not make any theorem/alternative definition about that.

Comment: However, it is nessesary for a sequence to be non-Cauchy for it to diverge to infinity.

Comment: @LiChunMin as far as I understand you, I cannot find the  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  (3n+2)  $ with the Cauchy definition, right?

Comment: @KarenSM yes. See Dave's comment. The sequence $(-1)^n$ isn't Cauchy too yet it doesn't diverge to infinity.

Comment: Non Cauchyness is equivalent to non convergence since $\Bbb{R}$ is complete. But diverging to infinity means more so you can't just say "it diverges to infinity because it doesn't converge"

Comment: @KarenSM It is easy to show that the sequence is monotone increasing, at which point we can say the limit is infinity (together with knowing that it doesn't converge). It didn't look like anyone cleared up that follow up question for you.

Comment: @LiChunMin Dave  Chessnerd321 Thanks for helping me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a Cauchy sequence is:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in  \mathbb{N}: \forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}: m,n \ge N \implies |a_m-a_n| < \epsilon$, and the negation of this definition is:

$\exists \epsilon > 0, \forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \exists m,n \in \mathbb{N}: m,n \ge N, |a_m - a_n| \ge \epsilon$.

For your sequence $a_n = 3n+2, n \ge 1$, choose $\epsilon = 1$ (your choice is $3$), for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, let $n =N, m = N+1$. Observe $m, n \ge N$, and $|a_m - a_n| = |a_{N+1} - a_{N}|= |3(N+1) - 2 - 3N+2|= 3 > 1= \epsilon $. Thus the sequence above is not Cauchy.

Comment: But with $\epsilon=2$ is still fine, right? I'm nervous because I put this in my exam

Comment: $\epsilon = 2$ works just fine. $2$ is better than $1$...

Answer (score 0):

You did not write the def'n of $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L.$ What you wrote in response to "Define what it means for $(a_n)_n$ to converge to $L$" was: " $(a_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence (which means ...) which converges to $L$."

The def'n of $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L$ is $$\forall r>0\;\exists m\;\forall n>m\;(|L-a_n|<r).$$ I have omitted specifying that $m,n\in \mathbb N.$ It is conventional that in "$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$", the values of $n$ are restricted to members of $\mathbb N$ unless  stated otherwise.